# Como usar ArrayList para preencher os dados do jasper report usando EntityManager / Datasource

Tags: spring-boot, jasper-reports, datasource

[imagem 1][1]
[imagem 2][2]
[imagem 3][3]
[imagem 4 (sql)][4]

Estou tentando gerar um relatório jasper na minha aplicação,  mas o objeto vem por meio de uma arraylist e com isso não consigo mapear e direcionar os fields lá no jrxml do relatório, já que quando fiz o layout no jasper studio eu tinha colocado os fields direto do banco de dados pela query no próprio jasper, porém quando trouxe pra minha aplicação springboot eu fiz todo o processo, mas não sei como eu consigo colocar os campos do relatório pra receber essas informações do arraylist que vem como lista de objetos sem deescrição para mapear cada campo das tabelas do banco de dados.
(Nas imagens fica mais fácil de entender).
está dando erro nos nomes que estavam nos fields como "id_aluno", "nome_aluno" etc. Pois esses nomes não estão vindo no objeto que vem da consulta sql com o entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);

Por gentileza, quem puder dá essa força ai.

```
@Repository
public class ReportRepository {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public ReportRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
    
    public List<Object> getReport(){
        String query = "select * from aluno al inner join aluno_endereco ae on al.id_aluno = ae.aluno_id\r\n"
+ "inner join aluno_saude als on als.aluno_id = ae.aluno_id\r\n"
+ "inner join bairro on bairro.id_bairro = ae.bairro_id\r\n"
+ "inner join nome_logradouro nl on nl.bairro_id = bairro.id_bairro\r\n"
+ "inner join municipio mun on mun.id_mun = ae.municipio_id\r\n"
+ "inner join classe_aluno ca on ca.aluno_id = al.id_aluno\r\n"
+ "inner join classe cl on cl.id_classe = ca.classe_id\r\n"
+ "inner join escola esc on esc.id_esc = cl.escola_id\r\n"
+ "inner join nivel n on n.id_nivel = cl.nivel_id\r\n"
+ "inner join raca_cor rc on rc.id_raca_cor = al.raca_cor_id\r\n"
+ "inner join sexo sx on sx.id_sexo = al.sexo_id\r\n"
+ "inner join responsavel_aluno resal on resal.aluno_id = al.id_aluno\r\n"
+ "inner join responsavel r on r.id_responsavel = resal.responsavel_id\r\n"
+ "inner join parentesco pa on pa.id_parentesco = resal.parantesco_id\r\n"
+ "inner join tipo_sanguineo ts on ts.id_tipo_sanguineo = als.tipo_sanguineo_id\r\n"
                + "order by cl.turma";
        
        var resultado = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
        return resultado.getResultList();
    }
}
```

```
(Resport.jrxml)
```

.......

```
</field>
<field name="rg_aluno" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="rg_data_emissao" class="java.sql.Date">

</field>
<field name="rg_orgao_expedidor" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="nome_mae" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="nome_pai" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="telefone_aluno" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="sexo_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="raca_cor_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="email" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="nis" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="aluno_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="bairro_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="nome_logradouro_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="municipio_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="numero" class="java.lang.String">
</field>
<field name="cep" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="complemento" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="ponto_referencia" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="id_aluno_end" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="id_aluno_saude" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="tipo_sanguineo_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="intolerancia_alimentar_desc" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="alergia_medicamento_desc" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="doenca_desc" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="medicacao_continua_desc" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="acompanhamento_medico_desc" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="deficiencia_desc" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="relatorio" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="id_bairro" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="nome_bairro" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="id_logradouro" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="descricao_logradouro" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="id_mun" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="nome_mun" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="uf_codigo" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="id_classe_al" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="classe_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="data_matricula" class="java.sql.Date">

</field>
<field name="ano_letivo" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="id_classe" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="nivel_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="escola_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="serie" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="turma" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="id_esc" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="nome_esc" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="codigo_inep" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="id_nivel" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="descricao_nivel" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="id_raca_cor" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="descricao_raca_cor" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="id_sexo" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="descricao_sexo" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="id_resp_aluno" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="responsavel_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="parantesco_id" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="id_responsavel" class="java.lang.Integer">

</field>
<field name="nome_resp" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="cpf_resp" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="rg_resp" class="java.lang.String">

</field>
<field name="nic" class="java.lang.String">



            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nome_esc}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>

            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[FICHA DE MATRICULA - 2023]]></text>
        
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Nome:]]></text>
        
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nome_aluno}.toUpperCase()]]>
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QDVZ.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c0vb.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDvM2.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRuXT.jpg
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2YkV.jpg
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Estou usando createNativeQuey e o resultado dela não está vindo (chave, valor), está vindo somente os valores. Eu preciso das chaves e o valores para poder usar esses parâmetros e colocar no jrxml para gerar um relatório. Pois como ele vem somente valores, não reconhece sem os nomes dos campos nos Fields do relatório.